# Unwanted Double Scroll Bars Showing up after download/upload

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in web design.

My friend wanted me to do a little work on his site, just changing some content.

here is the site: http://www.newavenuesolutions.net/manage.html

Every time I download the file to work on it and then upload it, these strange non-functional double scroll bars would show up.

Even when I tried just simply downloading the file, making ZERO changes, and then uploading it again, this same thing happened!

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to remove it on this particular page only is to remove the call to the jQuery customscroll plugin, since it seems kind of broken.

Note that on small monitors, this might mean that it has standard scroll bars instead of fancy ones, but that might be an acceptable compromise to you.

To remove the call to the plugin, which adds the fancy scroll bars, remove the following lines from just before the `</head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function() {
$( "div[rel='scrollcontent1']" ).customscroll( { direction: "vertical" } );});
</script>
```